# Add a input file with JSF 1.2

Tags: jsf, file-upload, richfaces, jsf-1.2

I need to upload in a form dedicated to upload files. In my project I can use JSF 1.2 and RichFaces 3.3.3 but I can't use the `<rich:fileUpload/>` because my client wants a simple input, just like `<input type="file"/>`.

If I could I would use Primeface's or Tomahawk's file upload, but I'm forbidden, I can't use other libraries, I also can't use Servlet 3.0 nether Apache fileupload. What can I do now? I've seen other similar questions, but they could use other libs, I just can't, I'm restricted...

Comment: Why a down vote? Comment instead of down vote and walk away ¬¬

Comment: It would be simplest to use a 3rd party control or library. As this is not an option you will have to start reading the MIME spec as you're going to be writing a MIME parser.

Comment: @McDowell yes I know it would be waaay simpler, I also did a version using a lib and it got rejected :/ I'm currently trying to use a servlet to receive the file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this issue with an acceptable solution I created a normal form and a servlet, the servlet receives the `multipart/form-data` request and uses the [`org.ajax4jsf.request.MultipartRequest`](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/3.3.X/3.3.3.Final/en/apidoc_impl/org/ajax4jsf/request/MultipartRequest.html) included in RichFaces 3.3.3 to parse the received parameters and the attached file, then I save the `File` instance in a session and I restore it inside the JSF context.

**xhtml:**

```
<a4j:form >
    <a4j:jsFunction name="finishUpload" 
            action="#{importacaoController.actionUploadArquivoDadosXX}"
            reRender="uploadedFile,globalMensagens" />
    <a4j:jsFunction
        name="tipoNaoSuportado" reRender="globalMensagens" action="#{importacaoController.actionTipoNaoSuportado }"
        />
</a4j:form>
<form target="uploader" id="uploaderForm" action="#{request.contextPath}/MyServlet"
    method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="position: absolute;margin: -210px 0 0 300px;">
    <div class="modulo-6-12">
        <label for="uploadFileField">Anexar arquivo</label><br/>
        <input type="file" id="uploadFileField" name="upload" onchange="jQuery('#uploaderForm').submit();" />
    <br />
    <small><h:outputText id="uploadedFile" value="#{importacaoController.arquivoConfig.name}" /></small>
    </div>
</form>
<iframe id="uploader" width="0" height="0" src="" style="display: none; border: 0; margin:0;padding:0;"></iframe>
```

***Servlet:***

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String encoding = request.getCharacterEncoding();
        if(encoding == null) request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        MultipartRequest mpRequest = new MultipartRequest(request,true,10*1024*1024,"importarXX");
        String field = "upload";
        Object o =mpRequest.getFile(field);
        if(o instanceof File)
        {
            File file = (File)o;
            HttpSession sess = request.getSession();
            String name = mpRequest.getFileName(field);

            Writer w = response.getWriter();
            w.write("<html><head><script>");
            if(!name.endsWith(".xls"))
            {

                w.write("parent.window.tipoNaoSuportado()" +
                        //"alert('Só são permitidos arquivos com extensão .xls');" +
                        "</script></head><body></body></html>");
                w.close();
                file.delete();
                return;
            }

            sess.setAttribute("importarXXFile", o);
            sess.setAttribute("importarXXFileName", name);
            w.write("parent.window.finishUpload();</script></head><body>Sucesso</body></html>");
            w.close();
        }
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public boolean actionUploadArquivoDadosXX(){
    flgTipoNaoSuportado = false;
    HttpSession sess = ((HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest()).getSession();
    File uploadedFile = (File) sess.getAttribute("importarXXFile");
    String uploadedFileName = (String) sess.getAttribute("importarXXFileName");
    boolean ret = false;

    if(uploadedFile != null && uploadedFileName != null){
        BeanArquivoUpload arquivo = new BeanArquivoUpload();
        arquivo.setFile(uploadedFile);
        arquivo.setName(uploadedFileName);
        arquivo.setFileSize(uploadedFile.length());
        setArquivoConfig(arquivo);
        ret = true;
    }
    else
    {
         setArquivoConfig(null);
    }

    sess.removeAttribute("importarXXFile");
    sess.removeAttribute("importarXXFileName");

    return ret;


}
```

Answer (score 2):

*It's been some time since I had to write a MIME parser for JSF, but this is what I remember about the process.*

You will need to write a parser to extract data from the `multi-part/formdata` payload. There is a good [overview of `multi-part/formdata` on the W3 site](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2).

You will need to decide whether to target:

- a non-JSF servlet with a plain form/controls
- a JSF servlet with a JSF form and a custom file-upload control

**Targeting a plain servlet**

This will be the simpler approach so long as the upload POST action doesn't need to invoke code that relies being in a JSF context (managed beans, etc.)

Your servlet parses the data from the input stream and acts on it as appropriate.

**Targeting a JSF view/action**

Here you will need to decorated the request (ideally with a [`HttpServletRequestWrapper`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequestWrapper.html)) to provide the parsed [parameters](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequestWrapper.html#getParameterMap%28%29) to the JSF framework. This would generally be done in a [filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) that detects the post type from the HTTP headers. Decisions need to be made about where the file data is stored prior to the invocation of any form actions and how you're going to expose that data to managed beans.

You also need to consider whether you're going to create a custom JSF control for the file upload input type or whether you can get away with plain HTML elements.

*It is worth examining the features of the parsers/controls you can't use to ensure you provide simple features - like a maximum payload size to prevent attackers uploading gigabytes of data to your application.*

Comment: Thank you, but after hours trying many ways to do the upload I found n Multipart implementation by Ajax4J that is included in RichFaces (`org.ajax4jsf.request.MultipartRequest`) so I don't need to implement it by myself :)

Answer (score 0):

I had previously faced the same issue. I solved the issue by opening a pop-up when user click on browse button and this new popup was directly linked to a servlet which supports file uploading and downloading.
Once a file was uploaded the pop-up was closed directly by the servlet calling window.close() on load of the body of servlet.
below are the changes done:

In addItem.jsp which prompts user for a file :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       ...
  function newWindow()
  {
    popupWindow = window.open('addItemImage.jsp','name','width=200,height=200');
  }
    ...
 </script>

     <f:view>
         <h:form id="search" onsubmit="return validateDetails()">
          ...

           <h:panelGroup>
                <font color="black">Item Image :</font>
           </h:panelGroup>
           <h:panelGroup>
                <input type="button" value="Upload Image" onClick="newWindow()"/>
           </h:panelGroup>

          ...
          </h:form>
      </f:view>
```

In the new pop-up window that was opened : addItemImage.jsp

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validate()
    {
        var file = document.getElementById("file").value;
        if(file == null || file == "")
            return true;
        if(file.indexOf(".jpg") == -1 && file.indexOf(".gif")  && file.indexOf(".bmp") == -1 && file.indexOf(".jpeg") == -1) 
        {
            alert("Invalid File Format!! Please upload jpg/bmp/gif");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    } 
</script>
<body>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="FileUploaderServler.view" onsubmit="return validate()">
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
        <input type="submit" value="Upload Image">
    </form>
</body>
```

This would post to a servlet which would then render the image and save it at a place.
FileUploaderServlet.java

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
    {
        List<FileItem> items = null;
        try 
        {
             MultipartHTTPServletRequest multipartHTTPServletRequest = new MultipartHTTPServletRequest(Connection.getRequest());
            items = new ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory()).parseRequest(multipartHTTPServletRequest);
        } 
        catch (FileUploadException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(!Util.isNullList(items))
        {
            for (FileItem item : items) 
            {
                if (!item.isFormField()) 
                {
                    String itemName = item.getFieldName();
                    InputStream filecontent = null;

                    try 
                    {
                        filecontent = item.getInputStream();
                    } 
                    catch (IOException e) 
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                   /* String currDirPath = System.getProperty("user.dir"); // C:\Users\KISHORE\Desktop\eclipse
                    File file = new File(currDirPath+"\\itemImages");*/
                    new File(Constants.ABS_FILE_PATH_TO_IMAGES).mkdir();
                    File fw = new File(Constants.ABS_FILE_PATH_TO_IMAGES+"\\"+Connection.getRequest().getSession().getId()+".jpg"); // E:\Kishore Shopping Cart\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\ShoppingCart\WEB-INF\itemImages\EC34EEE58065AD674192D3D57124F07E.jpg
                    fw.delete();
                    fw.createNewFile();
                    try 
                    {
                        item.write(fw);
                    } 
                    catch (Exception e) 
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.print("<html><title>Add Image to Item</title><body onload='window.close()'>Uploaded Successfully!!</body>");
        System.out.print("</html>");
    }
```

This servlet on completion of saving file at a place configured, would directly close the pop-up that was previously opened.

So this way I was able to use the managed bean, jsf 1.2 and achieve fiel uploading.
I found other ways on stackoverflow but felt it was a bit complex to implement.